# Php SimpleXMLElement Object to variable

Tags: php, xml, arrays, variables

Here is my Problem, below I have an Api script to manually input the xml object [user_token] to access user information based on the token. So to enter every attribute from the array I have used the code

```
foreach ($xml->result->data->users->entries->user_token as $user_token1) 
    echo $user_token1;
```

Which then gets pluged into

```
if ($oneall_curly->get (SITE_DOMAIN . "/users/" . $user_token1 . ".xml"))
{
$result = $oneall_curly->get_result ();
print_r (($result->body));
}
```

So after this Im not sure what is wrong I have searched over many answers on both stack overflow as well as php.net. I am certainly no expert really just a novice at coding php but would certainly appreciate some insight into this problem or help towards the code that creates the variable $user_token1

Thank you so very much for looking!

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[request] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [date] => Fri, 26 Jul 2013 12:18:36 +0200
        [resource] => /users.xml??page=1&order_direction=desc
        [status] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [flag] => success
                [code] => 200
                [info] => Your request has been processed successfully
            )

    )

[result] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [data] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [users] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [pagination] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [current_page] => 1
                                [total_pages] => 1
                                [entries_per_page] => 500
                                [total_entries] => 2
                                [order] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [field] => date_creation
                                        [direction] => desc
                                    )

                            )

                        [count] => 2
                        [entries] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [user_token] => 11111111-4444-bbbb-1111-111111111111
                                        [date_creation] => Wed, 24 Jul 2013 00:33:28 +0200
                                        [date_last_login] => Wed, 24 Jul 2013 02:08:44 +0200
                                        [num_logins] => 2
                                    )

                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [user_token] => 22222222-5555-aaaa-2222-333333333333
                                        [date_creation] => Wed, 24 Jul 2013 00:28:56 +0200
                                        [date_last_login] => Thu, 25 Jul 2013 07:08:20 +0200
                                        [num_logins] => 4
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

This is the simpleXML object I have output from previous code and this

```
$raw = "http://../../file.php";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($raw);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
return $xml;


// Get an element by its id attribute


// or, loop over all of the <rate> elements
foreach ($xml->result->data->users->entries->user_token as $user_token1) 
    echo $user_token1;





if ($oneall_curly->get (SITE_DOMAIN . "/users/" . $user_token1 . ".xml"))
{
    $result = $oneall_curly->get_result ();
    print_r (($result->body));
}
//Error
else
{
$result = $oneall_curly->get_result ();
echo "Error: " . $result->http_info . "\n";
}



?>
```

Comment: $oneall_curly is a php variable created by the Oneall social login SDK kit

Comment: i did print_r ($user_token1->body); and it shows nothing

Comment: I did var_dump($user_token1) it  the #'s together 


11111111-4444-bbbb-1111-11111111111122222222-5555-aaaa-2222-333333333333{"response":{"request":{"date":"Fri, 26 Jul 2013 13:32:14 +0200","resource":"\/users\/","status":{"flag":"error","code":404,"info":"The specified resource does not exist: http:\/\/docs.oneall.com\/"}}}}object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (4) { ["user_token"]=> string(36) "22222222-5555-aaaa-2222-333333333333" ["date_creation"]=> string(31) "Wed, 24 Jul 2013 00:28:56 +0200" ["date_last_login"]=> string(31) "Thu, 25 Jul 2013 07:08:20 +0200" ["num_logins"]=> string(1) "4" }

Comment: please note that this is after using the code below in the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this `$xml->result->data->users->entries`

You select this:

```
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [user_token] => 11111111-4444-bbbb-1111-111111111111
    [date_creation] => Wed, 24 Jul 2013 00:33:28 +0200
    [date_last_login] => Wed, 24 Jul 2013 02:08:44 +0200
    [num_logins] => 2
)

[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [user_token] => 22222222-5555-aaaa-2222-333333333333
    [date_creation] => Wed, 24 Jul 2013 00:28:56 +0200
    [date_last_login] => Thu, 25 Jul 2013 07:08:20 +0200
    [num_logins] => 4
)
```

Now you have an array of 2 `SimpleXMLElement Objects`. Now you can foreach

```
foreach ($xml->result->data->users->entries as $entry) {
    echo $entry->user_token;
}
```

Comment: so this is what happened I received the return on the first user token but not the second by using this code

foreach ($xml->result->data->users->entries->user_token as $user_token1){
    echo $user_token1->user_token1;
    }

do I need to do a foreach on the 

if ($oneall_curly->get (SITE_DOMAIN . "/users/" . $user_token1 . ".xml"))
{


to run every token?

Comment: Or you save the tokens in a temparary array. But then you need to loop twice. So I would put the if statement in the loop yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this type. `entries` is a main array. so you can store one variable then you execute via `foreach`

```
<?php
$user_token = $xml->result->data->users->entries;
foreach ($user_token as $user_token1){
    echo $user_token1->user_token;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Still unfortunately only returns the information from echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';

Comment: I did var_dump($user_token1) it the #'s together 11111111-4444-bbbb-1111-11111111111122222222-5555-aaaa-2222-333333333333{"respon‌​se":{"request":{"date":"Fri, 26 Jul 2013 13:32:14 +0200","resource":"\/users\/","status":{"flag":"error","code":404,"info":"The specified resource does not exist: http:\/\/docs.oneall.com\/"}}}}object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (4) { ["user_token"]=> string(36) "22222222-5555-aaaa-2222-333333333333"